# Accessing Arraylist contents from a different class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a simple program that takes username and password and prints them to the console. However, I have an arraylist in class "UserInfo" that stores the user information. I would like to print the user information by looping through the arraylist in a different class. Is it possible to access an arraylist in a different class?

For instance, in the class "output" I have a for loop that loops through the arraylist in the "UserInfo" class. This loop works if it is inside the "UserInfo" class. But it does not work when accessing the arraylist in a different class.

```
   Errors:
   UserForm.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
```

This should be the program outcome:

```
User 1:

Name: Jack
Password: 123
```

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
 public class UserForm{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    User u1 = new Info1("Jack", 123);
    User u2 = new Info2("Mack", 125);

    UserInfo d1 = new UserInfo();


    output v1 = new output(d1);
    Print p = new Print(v1);
    d1.addUser(u1);
    d1.addUser(u2);

    p.addPrint(d1);

    //p.UserList();//Prints number of users
    v1.outputDetails();// Prints user information
    //p.UserList();

    }

    }



class Print{

    //This class is used for printing the number of users
output out;

public Print(output out){
     this.out = out;
}
    private ArrayList<UserInfo> printDetails = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();

    public void addPrint(UserInfo s){
        printDetails.add(s);
     }

    public ArrayList<UserInfo> getUserList(){
        return printDetails;
    }

    public void UserList(){
        int i=1;
        for(UserInfo s : printDetails){

            System.out.println("User: "+i);
            //s.outputDetails();

            i++;
        }
    }
}


class output {
UserInfo userInfo;

public output(UserInfo userInfo){
     this.userInfo = userInfo;
}

    public void outputDetails(){
        int i=1;

        for(User m : userInfo.getUser()){//error addUser

            System.out.println("User: "+i);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Name: "+m.name);
            System.out.println("Password: "+m.password);
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        } System.out.println();
    }
}


class UserInfo{

     //This class is used to store the user information in an arraylist
     private ArrayList<User> addUser = new ArrayList<User>();

     public void addUser(User b){
        addUser.add(b);
     }

    public ArrayList<User> getUser(){
        return addUser;
    }



 }

class Info1 extends User {

    public Info1(String name, int password) {

        super(name, password);

    }

 }

 class Info2 extends User {

    public Info2(String name, int password) {

        super(name, password);

    }

 }

abstract class User{

    String name;
    int password;

    public User(String name, int password){
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPassword(){
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(){
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide your private `ArrayList` with a public getter, and you'll be able to access it.

Comment: Well, your method `getUser()` returns an `ArrayList` . I'd call it `getUsers`

Comment: What do you mean by 'But it does not work when accessing the arraylist in a different class.'? Are you not able to access the arraylist?

Comment: moonwave99 I do have a public getter. public ArrayList<User> getUser(){
        return addUser;
    }

Comment: nachokk I did change it to getUsers but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate `UserInfo` inside the `Output` class before you can use the `addUser` list that's in `UserInfo`. Then just call the `getUser()` method to return the list. `Output` has no `addUser` hence the `can not find symbol`

```
class output{

    UnserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();        <<<----------------

    public void outputDetails(){
        int i=1;

        for(User m : userInfo.getUser()){       <<<-----------------
            System.out.println("Name: "+m.name);

            System.out.println("\nPassword: "+m.password);

            i++;
        } 
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

> *" Now there is no errors but the program does not print the name and password! It only prints "User 1""*

It's not printing anything because the UserInfo object in theOutput class have nothing added. You need a constructor that takes a `UserInfo`

```
class output {
    UserInfo userInfo;

    public output(UserInfo userInfo){
         this.userInfo = userInfo;
    }

    ...
}
```

The in your `main` you pass the UserInfo to the `Output`

```
User u = new Info("Jack", 123);
UserInfo d1 = new UserInfo();
d1.addUser(u);

output v = new output(d1);

Print p = new Print();
p.addPrint(d1);

p.UserList();//Prints number of users
v.outputDetails();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now there is no errors but the program does not print the name and password! It only prints "User 1"

Comment: See my **Edit**. Think that should solve your problem.

Comment: Look very closely at the code. Is that how you have it?

Comment: So does the name and password go to the output then to the arraylist or the other way. Could you please tell me. Thanks

Comment: What happens is you need to fully complete the UserList with all the users before you pass it to the output. _Then_ you can out the all the users

Comment: The output make a copy of the user list you pass to it, and uses that copy to print. It cannot access the original cop that's in the main. It can only be passed a copy. So if you add more users after passing the list to the output, the output will still only print the first list past to it.

Comment: Ok. One more question. If I add another user in the main, do I have to change anything? Because right now the output does cannot hold two constructors!

Comment: So is that a good approach or bad approach if having to add multiple users. Are there any other ways?

Comment: You can keep adding all the users you want. Just don't instantiate the `output` class until you're finished adding users to the UserList. _Then_ intantiate the `output`, passing the `UserList` object to it.

Comment: I have edited my code above. Now I have added another user. Do I have to instantiate output class each time I create another user? I get errors If I don't! Is there a way to pass d1,d2 to the output class together output v = new output(d1,d2).

Comment: UserList is a list of Users. You only need One Use list. Keep adding new Users to the same UswerList. When your done adding. pass the list to the output. I'm going to sleep.

Comment: Read over all my commnets. You don't seem to be paying attention. What part of create output AFTER you all all the users. Your code above, you still try to add users after creating the output.